# Regular expression to parse two numbers from a line

Tags: java, regex

What I want to achieve is actually quite simple : 
I have lines that look similar to :

```
V123,V20  
10,9999  
100,V220
```

etc...

Basically many pairs of numbers with a leading letter / zero.
I want to be able to parse them using RegEx, what I've found so far in Java is :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*([1-9](?:\\d{0,2})).*",Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("V999,V50");
System.out.println(m.matches()); - return true
System.out.println(m.groupCount()); --> this one returns 0
```

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to (i) split and (ii) remove non digits characters?

Comment: What do you want to do?  All you've said is that you want to "_parse them_".  That could mean anything.

Comment: What is your expected output from above input?

Comment: The expected output is two numbers regardless of the input given (with letters or without)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] a = new String[] {"V123,V20", "10,9999", "100,V220"};

    for (String s: a) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\D0]*(\\d*)[\\D0]*(\\d*)",Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        System.out.println(m.matches());
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT

P.S.: if you have trailing letters, you can add \\D in the end:

```
"[\\D0]*(\\d*)[\\D0]*(\\d*)[\\D]*
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been a great help !

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    }
```